# add captcha in HTML from using Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony, bundle, captcha

Hi i want to use captcha in an html form in a Symfony 3.4 project , i installed and implemented  the captcha bundle (Gregwar's CaptchaBundle)successfully but in the bundle's documentation in the part of adding the captcha to the form they are working with symfony form builder but i am working with normal HTML form using requests . 
this is the code they provided in the bundle's documentation :

```
<?php
    use Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType;
    // ...
    $builder->add('captcha', CaptchaType::class); // That's all !
    // If you're using php<5.5, you can use instead:
    $builder->add('captcha', 'Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType');
    // ...
```

this is my html form where i want to add the captcha

```
    <form class="row" method="post"   action="{{path('envoyerchat')}}">
        <input type="text" name="test2">
        <input type="text" name="test1">
        <!-- add captcha here -->
        <!-- add captcha here -->
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

can i convert that code which works with fom builder to my html form ?